# How to save XML child nodes value to database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need help regarding saving XML data into MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response Code="200"><Description>http://sample.net</Description><URL>/Patient/PatientView.aspx?pid=642</URL></Response>
```

Now what I wanted to do is to get the value of the `<Description>` tag and the `<URL>` tag and combine them to become a complete url then save it to mysql database.

Comment: you'll need to parse the xml first, use `simplexml` for that, after you're done parsing, then use pdo to connect and make you insertions

Comment: thanks ill try your suggestion sir,:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See question here [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/8105267)

You can use SimpleXML (see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for parsing

```
$xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response Code="200"><Description>http://sample.net</Description><URL>/Patient/PatientView.aspx?pid=642</URL></Response>';

$response = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

$url = (string) $response->Description . (string) $response->URL;
```

`$url` will contain:

```
http://sample.net/Patient/PatientView.aspx?pid=642
```

Then use `PDO` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to store data into database:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sample (url) VALUES (:url)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: thank you on this @Sergey Kasatkin, ill try this one. :-)